# We are given the graphs of f and g below. Find (g o f)'(1) , i.e. the derivative of (g o f) at 1.

Tags: calculus

We are given the graphs of f  and g  below. Find (g o f)'(1) , i.e. the derivative of (g o f)  at 1.

[image]

my work is

let $$g(x) = x^2 + 2$$

$$f(x) = \sqrt{x+2}$$

i'm stuck , is my work correct and f and g is correct to get (g o f) and (g o f)'

please look well in the graph and compare between my suggestion f,g , is they correct or no ? 
any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions (as written now) are incorrect. Observe that $g(x)$ is the translation of $x^2$ two units to the right, i.e. $g(x) = (x-2)^2 = x^2 - 4x + 4$. Though it is slightly unclear, $f(x)$ is most likely $e^x$ (a quick check on Mathematica shows this).
Now we can apply the chain rule. Since $g$ is differentiable at $f(1) = e$ and $f$ is differentiable at 1, we have
$$ (g \circ f)'(1) = g'(f(1))f'(1) = g'(e)f'(1) = (2e - 4)(e) = 2e^2 - 4e.$$

Answer (score 0):

The composition $f \circ g$, of functions $f$ and $g$, is defined by the operation $ (f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$ for all $x$ in your domain. Since $g(x)= x^2+2$, and $f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}$, then $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))=f(x^2+2)=\sqrt{(x^2+2)+2}=\sqrt{x^2+4}$

Then take the derivative to find $(f \circ g)'$ and substitute x=1 as per usual :)

Comment: please look well in the graph and compare between my suggestion f,g , is they correct or no ?

Comment: Ah, I see. As explained by JackV and Nitin, the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ do not describe the graphs shown. However, the methodology is the same for whatever functions you wish to compose and derive. It seems that $f(x)=e^x$

Answer (score 0):

Your equations are incorrect. where you have $g(x) = x^2 + 2$ that isnt correct because that is saying you take the graph of $x^2$ and move it up two but clearly we move it to the right two so it should be $g(x) = (x-2)^2$.

Now for $f(x) = \sqrt{x+2}$ That is incorrect because when $x < -2$ we get a negative value under the squareroot which is undefined but by the graph we can see that we get a defined y value so we know it cant be correct. This equation is most likely $f(x) = e^x$.

Now we can take g(f(x)) and then take the derivative of that and plug in $x = 1$ into the derivative of that.